# Android How to dynamically change themes in all activities?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to dynamically switch background theme across all activities. But currently, I can only get it to switch on the current activity the switch is at. 
I have tried the following:

Using `setTheme` to set theme for other activities, but resulted in error: `cannot find symbol method setTheme(int)`:

```
ConstraintLayout homeActivity = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeLayout);
homeActivity.setTheme(R.style.darktheme);
```

Also tried `getTheme`, but resulted in error: `non-static method getTheme() cannot be referenced from a static context`:

```
Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
theme.applyStyle(R.style.darktheme,true);
```

Please provide guidance on how to fix these errors, or alternative approaches.

---

**Update**, New problem encountered with Preference Manager:
This is what is currently implemented, when switch the dark theme should be displayed across activities but app goes completely black without error:

```
myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){

                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(DisplaySettingActivity.this)
                        .edit()
                        .putInt("ActivityTheme", R.style.darktheme)
                        .commit();
                DisplaySettingActivity.this.recreate();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Saham's answer, this can be solved by subclassing Activity and overriding onCreate():

```
public class ThemeChangeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Gets the saved theme ID from SharedPrefs, 
        // or uses default_theme if no theme ID has been saved
        int theme = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("ActivityTheme", R.id.default_theme);
        // Set this Activity's theme to the saved theme
        setTheme(theme);
        // Continue with creation
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Now, make all of the Activities you want to change the theme for extend from ThemeChangeActivity. Whenever you want to change the theme for your Activities, you can just use this:

```
PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .edit()
    .putInt("ActivityTheme", R.id.theme_you_want_to_set)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you please see the update to the question on problems that occurred while implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a baseActivity which alters theme, and then subclass that activity and modify your theme. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you please see the update to the question on problems that occurred while implementing this.

Comment: Show R.style.darktheme

Comment: Using this method isn't working for me. accentColor, colorPrimary, etc are not changing. The only thing that's changing is the statusBar/navigationBar. I tried prefixing the attributes with *android* namespace but didn't work.